# How to check if a user inputed answer has letters, and if so, how would you just default that answer into a 0?

Tags: ios, swift

Heres the code I have so far, now when a user inputs any letter, my label display nothing, what I would like to figure out is how to turn that nothing "", into a 0. I tried doing an if statement on my "label.txt ="'s but that didn't pan out. What would be a better way of finding my desired results?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var game1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var game2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var game3: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var series: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var average: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var high: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    @IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        guard
                let text1 = game1.text,
                let text2 = game2.text,
                let text3 = game3.text
        else { return }

        guard
                let game1Results = Int(text1),
                let game2Results = Int(text2),
                let game3Results = Int(text3)
        else { return }

        let gameResultsArray = [game1Results, game2Results, game3Results]
        let sumArray = gameResultsArray.reduce(0, +)
        let positiveArray = gameResultsArray.filter {
            (item: Int) -> Bool in return item > 0
        }

        var avgArrayValue = 0

        if positiveArray.count == 0
        {
            avgArrayValue = 0
        }else {
            avgArrayValue = sumArray / positiveArray.count
        }

        series.text = "\(sumArray)"
        average.text = "\(avgArrayValue)"
        if let maximumVal = gameResultsArray.max() {
        high.text = String(maximumVal)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need, convert `String` to `Int` and give the default 0. Instead of using the `guard let return` use this method:

Instead of this:

```
guard let game1Results = Int(text1) else { return }
```

Use this:

```
let game1Results = Int(text1) ?? 0
```